# PYQt5 application freezes even with multithreading Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5

````
```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import html.parser
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import re
from instagrapi import Client
import time
import csv
import threading

class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int, str)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

        # Add the callback to our kwargs
        self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except Exception as ea:
            print(ea)
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done


class Tasks(QObject):
    result: object

    def __init__(self):
        super(Tasks, self).__init__()

        self.pool = QThreadPool()
        self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(1)
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()



class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(MainWindow)
        self.thread_pool = QThreadPool()
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        
        MainWindow.setObjectName("ID Finder")
        MainWindow.resize(700, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 white, stop: 0.4 rgba(152, 65, 30, 40),stop:1 rgba(0, 200, 230, 200));")

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.submit1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.submit1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 290, 93, 28))
        self.submit1.setObjectName("Wake Bot")
        self.submit1.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;color:rgba(255,255,255,250);border-style: ridge;border-width : 2px; border-radius: 10px;border-color: cyan ;padding : 6px")

        
        self.label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('instagram.webp')
        self.label3.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label3.setGeometry(200,-15,250,250)
        self.label3.setStyleSheet('background-color : transparent')

        self.userinput = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.userinput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 200, 531, 41))
        self.userinput.setObjectName("userinput")
        self.userinput.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

        self.userinput2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.userinput2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 380, 220, 21))
        self.userinput2.setObjectName("userinput2")
        self.userinput2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        
        self.refresh = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.refresh.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 330, 93, 28))
        self.refresh.setObjectName("refresh")
        self.refresh.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;border-style: ridge ;border-width : 2px; border-radius: 10px;border-color: black ;padding : 6px")
        
        
        self.tb = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.tb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90,410,531,28))
        self.tb.setObjectName("tb")
        self.tb.setAcceptRichText(True)
        self.tb.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.tb.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

        
        self.pbar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(251, 475, 200, 25)
        
  
        # adding action to push button
        
  
        
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label2.setText("Enter Username")
        self.label2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);color:rgba(225,55,65,220);border-style: ridge ;border-width : 2px; border-radius: 10px;border-color: red ;padding : 1px;")
        font = QtGui.QFont("Bahnschrift")
        self.label2.setFont(font)
        self.label2.setGeometry(90,170,175,28)
        font2 = QtGui.QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(13)
        self.label2.setFont(font2)
        

        self.label5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label5.setText("Enter File Name")
        self.label5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);color:rgba(225,55,65,220);border-style: ridge ;border-width : 2px; border-radius: 10px;border-color: red ;padding : 1px;")
        font = QtGui.QFont("Bahnschrift")
        self.label5.setFont(font)
        self.label5.setGeometry(320,375,175,28)
        font2 = QtGui.QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(13)
        self.label5.setFont(font2)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        

        ##Action Center
        self.submit1.pressed.connect(self.start_long_task1)
        self.refresh.clicked.connect(self.clear_text)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    

    def start_long_task1(self):
        self.submit1.setEnabled(False)
        worker = Worker(self.finderfunc)
        worker.signals.result.connect(self.initiald)
        worker.signals.finished.connect(self.progress_fn)
        worker.signals.progress.connect(self.progress_fn)
        
        # pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        self.thread_pool.start(worker)


    def initiald(self):
        self.tb.append("Rise and Shine")

    def finderfunc(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.tb.append("Initializing ..")
        bot = Client()
        bot.handle_exception
        try:
            bot.load_settings('ig_dump.json')
        except:
            bot.dump_settings('ig_dump.json')
        bot.login(username ="",password="")

        id_list = []

        for x in range(0,101):
            try:
                user_id = bot.user_id_from_username(f'{self.userinput.text().strip()}{x}')
                id_list.append(user_id)
                time.sleep(25)
                self.pbar.setValue(x)

            except Exception as e1:
                self.tb.append(str(e1))
                self.pbar.setValue(x)

        link_list = []

        for id in id_list:
            try:
                user_info = bot.user_info(id).dict()
                if user_info['is_private'] is True:
                    pass
                    
                else:
                    if int(user_info['follower_count'])<=20:

                        link_list.append((["https://www.instagram.com/" + user_info['username'],str(user_info['follower_count'])]))
                        
                    else:
                        pass

            except Exception as e2:
                self.tb.apppend(str(e2))
        with open(f"{self.userinput2.text()}.csv","w") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(link_list)
            
    def completep(self):
        self.tb.append("Completed . . .")

    def clear_text(self):
        self.userinput.clear()
        self.tb.clear()
        self.userinput2.clear()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Account Finder App"))
        self.submit1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Wake Bot"))
        self.refresh.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Refresh"))
        # self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ACCOUNT FINDER"))
        self.label2.setText(_translate("MainWindow","Enter Username"))
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Window()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    ```
````

Hello everybody. The main purpose of my application is to filter public Instagram accounts with followers lesser than 20 within a range of 0,101. User enters a username in input box, declares a file name and starts the process. It was working without multithreading, but the screen used to freeze until everything is done. I tried multithreading, but it's freezing again and making it impossible to keep track of the progress. MY OS is Win10, I tried it on different win10 computers but same result. My RAM is 16GB(8+8). I tried 10 different approaches, none of them worked. I am new to multithreading so I am pretty sure I'm missing an important part but couldn't see it. This might look duplicate, but I digged several other questions here, none of them seem to worked. Any help,criticism,ideas are most welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. don't use generic exceptions, otherwise you will not know *what* raised it; 2. don't edit/merge pyuic generated code, as it can cause silent errors or unexpected behavior; properly follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) instead; 3. the whole concept of using threading is to not block the UI, which is exactly what you're doing in `progress_fn`, since you're using `time.sleep()`, which doesn't make any sense; 4. ensure that you provide a valid [mre] (it must be *both* minimal *and* reproducible).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to recreate the code following your instructions. Would you mind if I ask another question?

Comment: What do you mean by "ask another question"? If you want to provide a more appropriate code and improve your post, just [edit] it. If you have a *different* question, then create a new post, as each post can only contain *one* question or be related to *one* specific aspect.

Comment: No no I meant can I ask you something related to this code? I know I should create a new question topic for a different thing. After some exception tweaks, I realized that I omited **kwargs on main function that's why it failed. However, now I see this "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread" but it seems to be working. I'm in a desperate and tired situation so I'm sorry if talk nonsense at some point

Comment: Without knowing how you fixed the code, it's impossible to tell you what is the exact cause, but that error always happens when any QObject tries to reparent or create another QObject in the wrong thread. The most common cause, is trying to create a Qt widget or altering an existing one from outside the main thread, which is forbidden, since UI elements are *not* thread safe and can only be created in the thread of the QApplication (which should always be the main one).

Comment: I changed def finderfunc(self) to ''def finderfunc(self,*args, **kwargs):'' and I deleted the progress_fn. I did add "self.pbar.setValue(x)" inside for loop of finderfunc. These are the only changes I made. The app destroyed itself with warning 'QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?'after working up to %31. Guess I'll just quit

Comment: Please don't use comments for code, as it's impossible to read it or understand where the problem might be. As already said, [edit] your question and apply the changes *there*.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. I am not very familiar with rules here. I edited the code. Now it throws the errors I mentioned on my previous comment and closes itself

Comment: As already said, UI elements can **not** be accessed from external threads, which is exactly what you're doing by calling `self.pbar.setValue()` within `finderfunc`, which is run in that thread. Note that while it is technicall possible to run a given function in a thread (similarly to what is done when using the python `Thread()`), it's generally discouraged in Qt, as it usually makes the code unnecessarily complex and prone to issues. You should instead move that function in the `run()` of the worker, and if you need to "set it up" with UI values, just set them when creating the worker.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate that. Guess I need to work on it a bit more. Have a great day/night.